# double input and extra letter in list in Sagemath

Tags: python, input, sage

I'm a newbie in python and [sagemath](http://www.sagemath.org/), so it's confusing me.

with the following code, I've got a `u` character before each element of the list.

```
str = raw_input()
chr = list(str)
print chr

# input: "alma"
# output: [u'a', u'l', u'm', u'a']
```

furthermore when I run the project the input field appears twice. first when I have to write, and after it when I press enter (appears with the entered text)

[image: 1]

Comment: The `u` makes the character a [unicode string](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#python-2-x-s-unicode-support)

Comment: how can I make it disappear? I'm trying to make a basic encrypter and it is confusing in the output.
it's just appears when I print it out at once, with for loop print there is no extra u

Comment: Use [`str.encode()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode)

Comment: @Finwood thanks! that solved the extra u problem!

Comment: I have a feeling that `raw_input()` in Sage Math Cloud isn't so good - see https://github.com/sagemathinc/smc/issues/358 if, as I believe, this is suboptimal to double stuff.